# "/dev/**** No such device" error coming even with valid charachter device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a kernel driver in `drivers/char/new_driver.c` . 
This new driver registers two new devices `/dev/device1` and `/dev/device2` by calling `misc_register()` api.

```
error = misc_register(&device1);
error = misc_register(&device2);

static struct miscdevice device1 = {
    MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    "device1",
    &device1_fops
};

static struct miscdevice device2 = {
    MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    "device2",
    &device2_fops
};
```

When I load the module I see that 2 two devices are getting created properly in `/dev/device1` and `/dev/device2`

But when I try to **`write/read`** operation on this device it gives error saying that there is **"No such device "** .

Any idea what causes this type of error ?  Anything missing in the driver code ?

Comment: Are the expected `major` and `minor` numbers showing up in `/dev` when you list them, i.e. via `ls -l /dev/device*` ?

Comment: Yes I see , 10 58 and 10 59 

crw------- 1 root root 10, 58 Mar 31 18:26 /dev/device1
crw------- 1 root root 10, 59 Mar 31 18:26 /dev/device2

Comment: @Shivaprasad This is permission issue (as you can see the same thing through ls -l command). Only root user have the permission to access the device. So change the permission for device1 and device2 or try to read or write from the root itself

Comment: @vinod  I dont think its permission issue. I logged in as root and try to do something like this . % echo "Hello"  > /dev/device1  but this also resulted in same error .

Comment: @Shivaprasad I think it should work at least with root user. But I can't say exactly what are you missing. BTW I have attached sample code and procedure in my answer. So follow the same.

Answer (score 0):

I still believe that this is permission issue. I am attaching the sample code (without any real implementation) skeleton. Please have a look into it.

```
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int sample_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);
    return 0;
}

static int sample_close(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filp)
{
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t sample_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,
                      size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);
    return len; /* Not doing anything with the data */
}

static ssize_t sample_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf,
                      size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);
    return len; /* Not do anything with the data */
}
static const struct file_operations sample_fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
    .write   = sample_write,
    .read    = sample_read,
    .open    = sample_open,
    .release = sample_close,
};
struct miscdevice sample_device = {
    .minor = MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    .name = "device1",
    .fops = &sample_fops,
};

static int __init misc_init(void)
{
    int error;

    error = misc_register(&sample_device);
    if (error) {
        pr_err("can't misc_register :(\n");
        return error;
    }
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit misc_exit(void)
{
    misc_deregister(&sample_device);
    pr_info("Maverick: %s func :\n",__func__);
}

module_init(misc_init)
module_exit(misc_exit)

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Sample Misc Driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Vinod Maverick <vinodmaverickr007@gmail.com>");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Then compile the driver:

```
make
sudo insmod misc_sample.ko
ilab@SSID-iLBPG3:~/vinod/ldd$ echo "hello" > /dev/device1
-bash: /dev/device1: Permission denied
ilab@SSID-iLBPG3:~/vinod/ldd$ sudo su
root@SSID-iLBPG3:/home/ilab/vinod/ldd# echo "hello" > /dev/device1
```

However I have not any code inside the read/write callback but still you can see the dmesg without any error

```
root@SSID-iLBPG3:/home/ilab/vinod/ldd# dmesg
[2903599.416005] Maverick: misc_init func :
[2903623.966281] Maverick: sample_open func :
[2903623.966292] Maverick: sample_write func :
[2903623.966295] Maverick: sample_close func :
root@SSID-iLBPG3:/home/ilab/vinod/ldd#
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who still has this problem, I managed to fix it by changing my minor number from a crazy high number (999) to a more reasonable number (71). Here's my resulting miscdevice struct:

```
static struct miscdevice chrdev = {
    .minor = 71,
    .name = "tracefunc",
    .fops = &chrdev_fops,
    .mode = S_IRUGO,
};
```